# PHP code to be executed only once

Tags: php

I have a php code I want to execute only once, that is it it should get loaded when it is getting installed for the first time, and the second time it should not execute. I tried with `for` and `if` condition but it didn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
$table = self::checkTablesExist();

    if(empty($table)) { 
    self::createTables();

    self::createRootUser(self::$preflight_config);
        if(self::$preflight_config->sample_data == 1) { 
            self::installSampleData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "should get loaded when it is getting installed for the first time" ?

Comment: What doesn't work? What does checkTablesExist() do? did it detect the tables already existing?

Comment: The data gets populated to the database, 
checkTableExist method checks for the table exist in the particular database

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a system similar to database locks.

So, the first time the code is run you create a file `run.lock`, empty, it doesn't matter, then on every other execution check the existence of that file, if it exists, the code has been run, otherwise you should run the code.

Take care to create the file in a permanent location, NOT something like `/tmp`

Or maybe better, if those tables in the DB exist, don't run the code.

Comment: Otherwise you can give a run.lock file with installation which can be deleted once tables are created. Execute your table creation code only if this file is present. eg. if(file_exists("run.lock")){ create tables}

Answer (score 0):

This all depends what you're trying to do, what i can see from your question is you're trying to install a mysql data table... This is correct, you should check if table exists..

```
<?php
if (mysql_num_rows("show tables like `tablename`")!==1) {

  // Install table

}
?>
```

If ever you want to run code only once based on something totally different, i.e. not relying on a database, you would best use flat filing:

```
<?php
if (file_exists("should-we-run.cfg") && file_get_contents("should-we-run.cfg")=="Y") {

  // Execute code
  file_put_contents("should-we-run.cfg","No");
  // OR
  unlink("should-we-run.cfg");

}
?>
```

Comment: And how do you plan to have a file `should-we-run.cfg` before any other code is executed? Making a script that creates this file is not only overhead, but also that script could be re-run in order to recreate that file, so his problematic code could be re-run.

Comment: So flip the rule, if the file is not present -> execute code and create the file (empty) and just use file_exists(); I dont really see an overhead issue unless we're talking huge performance requirements... then use a database config table to determine booleans indexes